# Obtaining a list of user-relevant processes/windows

Tags: c++, windows

So, I'm building a program that conditionally copies some files based on whether or not a user-defined process is running. Now, since the user is choosing the process, I want to filter the processes they can select down to what they really care about. Essentially I just want the processes/windows that can be alt-tabbed to. I've found a few ways of getting the running processes, but I haven't had much luck figuring out how to filter them down to what I'm looking for. Right now, this is the code I'm using to get the process names & window names, but I feel like there's probably a better way to do it:

(FYI, I'm using QT for this, so that's where the QString and QStringLists are coming from)

```
HWND hwnd_current = GetWindow(GetDesktopWindow(), GW_CHILD);
QStringList process_list;
do {
    wchar_t str_window_name[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD pid;
    DWORD exStyles = (DWORD)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd_current, GWL_EXSTYLE);
    DWORD styles = (DWORD)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd_current, GWL_STYLE);

    if(!((exStyles & WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW) == 0 && (styles & WS_CHILD) == 0)){
        continue;
    }
    if(!GetWindowText(hwnd_current, str_window_name, MAX_PATH)){
        continue;
    }
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd_current, &pid);
    if(pid == GetCurrentProcessId()){
        continue;
    }

    wchar_t fileName[MAX_PATH];
    LPWSTR file_name;
    HANDLE hProcess;
    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pid);
    if(hProcess){
        DWORD dwSize = MAX_PATH;
        QueryFullProcessImageName(hProcess, 0, fileName, &dwSize);
        file_name = PathFindFileName(fileName);
    }
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    QString boxString = QString("[");
    #ifdef UNICODE
    QString q_file_name = QString::fromStdWString(file_name);
    QString q_str_window_name = QString::fromStdWString(str_window_name);
    #else
    QString q_file_name = QString::fromStdString(file_name);
    QString q_str_window_name = QString::fromStdString(str_window_name);
    #endif
    boxString.append(q_file_name);
    boxString.append("] ");
    boxString.append(q_str_window_name);

    if(!q_file_name.isEmpty() && !q_str_window_name.isEmpty() && !pNameList.contains(boxString) && !process_list.contains(q_file_name)){
        if(!q_str_window_name.endsWith("MSCTFIME UI") && !q_str_window_name.endsWith("Default IME")){
            process_list.append(q_file_name);
            pNameList.append(boxString);
        }
    }

} while (hwnd_current = GetNextWindow(hwnd_current, GW_HWNDNEXT));
```

Any advice would be very appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty similar to how the [taskbar filters windows](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070117-01/?p=28373).

You seem to be pretty close but you should check if the window is visible and `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` allows tool windows to be [treated as a normal window](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071008-00/?p=24863).